# REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES issue detected by google even though we don't have one

Tags: actionscript-3, google-play, apk, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

App build with ActionScript3/Harman SDK but we don't even have REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES declared in our xml.

Also, I already checked the APK via Android Studio, the AndroidManifest doesn't contain also REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES.

Any fix or advice for this? Thank you.

We checked our SDKs/ANE DISTRIQT and none of them that we are using is using the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES.

Comment: What you declare in AndroidManifest.xml and what is included in the final APK doesn't have to be the same as used libraries can add entries in AndroidManifest.xml as well. Therefore you should use a decompiler like [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) and look at version of AndoridManifest.xml that is included in your generated APK file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all of the available APKs for your application.

Google will check all available versions of your application so even if your update doesn't have the permission an older build may have. When updating you may have an older version available for different users.

Go through and disable or remove all older versions as part of the update have this permission before releasing.